# Only apply virtual host when the server name is used as host

Tags: apache, virtualhost

So I have a project in folder `htdocs/project`. I need to access this project via domain `project.xx` to test subdomain `mod_rewrite`. To do this, I modified my `hosts` file to map the `project.xx` to `127.0.0.1`.

Then, I have created a virtual host in apache using this code:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName project.xx
    ServerAlias www.project.xx
    DocumentRoot C:/xampp/htdocs/project/
</VirtualHost>
```

It works as expected and when navigating to `http://project.xx` I end up on site running in `C:/xampp/htdocs/project/`.

I was just editing something else and I have discovered that something is wrong - navigating to `127.0.0.1` will **also** take me to my `project` site.

How do I prevent the virtual host setting from affecting whole localhost? I only want to go to my `project` when browser sends `project.xx` as the `Host` header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I learned on #httpd IRC chanell, it's required that you also set virtual host for the localhost itself, once you started using localhost.

This means that before matching the domain `project.xx`, a rule for `127.0.0.1` and `localhost` muse exist - so that if the domain isn't specified, default behavior will be used:

```
#Rule for localhost as it normaly behaves
<VirtualHost *:80>
    #IP and `localhost` domain name
    ServerName 127.0.0.1
    ServerAlias localhost
    #The normal document root
    DocumentRoot C:/xampp/htdocs/
</VirtualHost>
#Rule for your project
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName project.xx
    ServerAlias www.project.xx
    DocumentRoot C:/xampp/htdocs/project/
</VirtualHost>
```